# ms access, need to get all rows with a distinct column

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called "parts" which stores information on electrical connectors including contacts, backshells etc. all parts that are part of an assembly have a value in a column called "assemblyID". There is also a column called "partDefID", in this column connectors will have a value of 2, contacts will be 3. I need to get rows for all connectors that have a unique assemblyID. It's easy to get rows that represent connectors just by selecting rows with a partDefID of 2 but this will return multiple rows of connectors that may be part of the same assembly. I need only those rows of connectors with a unique assemblyID. How can I do this?
see image below:
[image: access screenshot]

what I am trying to get is just ONE of the rows shown below, any one of them would be fine as they are all part of the same assembly.
[just one of these rows needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBaUJ.png)

[update]
it seems my question was not well formed and the use of images is frowned upon. Inserting a text version of my table looked REALLY horrible though! I'll try to do better. yes, I'm a newb at both sql AND this website

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images. Also; Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: For *any* one row use `TOP`: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM parts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one "connector" row per assembly ID, you can filter with a subquery. Assuming that `PartRefID` is a unique key:

```
select *
from parts as p
where [PartRefID] = (
    select max(p1.[PartRefID])
    from parts as p1
    where p1.[AssemblyID] = p.[AssemblyID] and p1.[PartDefID] = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT assemblyid,count(partdefid)
FROM parts
WHERE partdefid=2
GROUP BY partdefid,assemblyid
HAVING COUNT(partdefid)=1
```

Comment: thanks! however pasting this into an access query window gives the following error: "your query does not include the specified expression 'description' as part of an aggregate function"

Comment: Oh sorry, I was wrong, I modified the answer