# MS access join two tables, get unique rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is a modification to a previous question [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259029/ms-access-need-to-get-all-rows-with-a-distinct-column/65259576#65259576) , I hope the proper thing to do is start a new thread.
I have a table called Parts, PartRefID is the PK

```
PartRefID   PartDefID   AssemblyID
1           2           c63df10b-8250-4aa5-9889-9e8046331dbf
11          1           db51f4a8-3ffa-41f7-81c1-a9accbbb299a
67          6           136fc5d8-7b65-41b5-bca3-7d4180a1e0ab
77          5           38fa8b7a-2945-4546-8eab-7865a1e515b2
133         2           c63df10b-8250-4aa5-9889-9e8046331dbf
134         6           136fc5d8-7b65-41b5-bca3-7d4180a1e0ab
```

I need to extract rows with a unique AssemblyID. This was answered by GMB with the following sql:

```
select *
from parts as p
where [PartRefID] = (
    select max(p1.[PartRefID])
    from parts as p1
    where p1.[AssemblyID] = p.[AssemblyID] and p1.[PartDefID] = 2
)
```

which worked beautifully. However requirements have changed and I must ignore the PartDefID field and there could also be AssemblyID's which represent parts I do not want.
The AssemblyID's shown in the above table represent an electrical connector part.
Electrical connector parts will ALWAYS have a Partclass of 1 which is defined in another table called PartDefinitions shown here:

```
PartDefID   PartClass   PartNumber
1           1           MS27467T23F55P
2           1           330-00186-09
3           2           336-00024-00
4           2           336-00022-00
5           1           MS27468T23F55S
6           1           330-00184-09
```

with my limited sql knowledge I decided a join was necessary and came up with the following code:

```
SELECT Parts.*, PartDefinitions.PartClass 
From PartDefinitions 
INNER Join Parts 
On PartDefinitions.PartDefID = Parts.PartDefID 
Where (((PartDefinitions.PartClass) = 1))
```

this gets me close, it produces all the parts in the parts table which are connectors. However there are some duplicate AssemblyID's.
what I need is to produce the following:

```
PartRefID   PartDefID   AssemblyID
1           2           c63df10b-8250-4aa5-9889-9e8046331dbf
11          1           db51f4a8-3ffa-41f7-81c1-a9accbbb299a
67          6           136fc5d8-7b65-41b5-bca3-7d4180a1e0ab
77          5           38fa8b7a-2945-4546-8eab-7865a1e515b2
```

my apologies if I have not made a clear and concise question
thanks for any help
and thanks again GMB

Comment: Just a tip, but sample data like c6 and db are so much easier to read than c63df10b-8250-4aa5-9889-9e8046331dbf and db51f4a8-3ffa-41f7-81c1-a9accbbb299a. Make it easy to assist you.

Comment: been trying unsuccessfully to edit and line the columns up

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter by the `PartClassId` in both the subquery and the outer query:

```
select p.*, pd.PartClass 
From Parts as p inner join
     PartDefinitions as pd 
     on pd.PartDefID = p.PartDefID 
where pd.PartClassId = 1 and
      p.pPartRefID = (select max(p2.pPartRefID)
                      from parts as p2 inner join
                           PartDefinitions as pd2
                           on pd2.PartDefID = pd.PartDefID
                      where p2.AssemblyID = p.AssemblyID and
                            p2.PartClassId = 1
                     )
```

Comment: if you say so :) but I get a syntax error when I plug this into the access query editor. unfortunately it gives no clue as to the error..

Comment: my apologies. The sql statement I provided above that I said got me close is using a different table which I did not show in the body of the question. I should probably scrap this question and reformulate it.

Comment: it said "syntax error in query expression 'pds.PartClassid = 1 and p.pPartRefID = (select max(p2.pPartRefID) from parts as p2 inner join PartDefinitions as pd2 on pd2.PartDefID = pd.PartDefID where p2.assemblyID = p.assemblyID and p2.PartClassid = 1)

Comment: I also edited the question and replaced the table I inserted by mistake with the correct one. Again, my apologies